# Given a set of points or vectors, find the set of N points that are closest to each other

Tags: optimization, vector, cluster-analysis

I have for example 100 vectors each has a dimension of 12. I would like to find for example 8 vectors that are closest to each other. In other words, the top 8 matching vectors. I may use Euclidean or Manhattan distance as a measure metric to quantify the similarity between the vectors. An initial thinking reveals that I could formulate this problem as a 0-1 nonlinear programming which is NP hard to solve as the number of vectors increases. I also went through the k-means clustering algorithm but it does not use the Euclidean distance as a measure. Any idea which algorithm can target this problem. The reason I am asking is because I am sure this problem was addressed in the literature but I could not find such algorithm.

Comment: I think you need to define the distance metric so the problem can be well defined: how a set of N points are defined to be closer than another set? Regarding the metric the problem can be more or less difficult. [This method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) may be of interest to you.

Comment: For future reference, Mathematics Stack Exchange or Operations Research Stack Exchange would be better places for questions like this, both due to their user bases and and their support for LaTeX (mathematical notation).

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be formulated as a quadratic or linear integer program:

The quadratic model can look like:

```
  min sum((i,j), x(i)*x(j)*dist(i,j))
      sum(i, x(i)) = 8
      x(i) ∈ {0,1}
```

The linear MIP model is a variant of the quadratic model:

```
  min sum((i,j), y(i,j)*dist(i,j))
      sum(i, x(i)) = 8
      y(i,j) >= x(i)+x(j)-1
      x(i) ∈ {0,1} 
      y(i,j) ∈ [0,1]
```

We can refine things by only considering distances with `i < j` (essentially no double counting).

Instead of summing over all distances, we can also minimize the maximum distance in our selected points:

```
 min z
     z >= y(i,j)*dist(i,j)   for all i<j
     sum(i, x(i)) = 8
     y(i,j) >= x(i)+x(j)-1 
     x(i) ∈ {0,1} 
     y(i,j) ∈ [0,1]
```

These models are independent of what metric or dimensionality you use. Whether using Euclidean or Manhattan distances or whether you normalize or use weights, the models stay the same. The same thing for whether you have low- or high-dimensional data. These models just need a distance matrix.

The MIP models solve quite fast with Gurobi. With random data using your sizes (select 8 points from 100 using 12-dimensional coordinates), these models take 50 and 9 seconds for the linear sum and max model to find proven optimal solutions. Some more details are [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/10/finding-cluster-of-closest-points.html).

For a 2d data set we can plot the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jérôme Richard that the distance measure needs to be clarified. Is it the sum of the Euclidean lengths of the 56 line segments connecting pairs of the eight selected points, or the maximum distance between any pair, or what?

That said, if "similarity" is the goal, we might ask which eight points are contained in the smallest possible ball or box. Finding the smallest ball is a convex quadratic problem and finding the smallest hyperrectangle has a nonconvex objective (I think), but finding the vectors that fit in the smallest hypercube is easy to formulate as a mixed integer linear program.

Answer (score 0):

with OPL CPLEX you can solve this both with [Mathematical Programming](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/closestpointsclustermip.mod) and [Constraint Programming](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/closestpointsclustercpo.mod).

Math prog:

```
int scale=1000000;

int nbdim=2;
int m=8;
int n=50;

range dim=1..nbdim;
range points=1..n;

float x[p in points][d in dim]=rand(scale)/scale;

float distance[p1 in points][p2 in points]=sqrt(sum(d in dim)((x[p1][d]-x[p2][d])^2));

// Should we keep that point ?
dvar  boolean which[points];

dexpr float maxDist=max(ordered i,j in points) distance[i][j]*((which[i]==1) && (which[j]==1));

minimize maxDist;
subject to
{
  sum (p in points) which[p]==m;
}

{int} chosenPoints={k | k in points:which[k]==1};
```

Constraint Programming:

```
using CP;

int scale=1000000;

int nbdim=2;
int m=8;
int n=50;

range dim=1..nbdim;
range points=1..n;

float x[p in points][d in dim]=rand(scale)/scale;

float distance[p1 in points][p2 in points]=sqrt(sum(d in dim)((x[p1][d]-x[p2][d])^2));

// which point for as the m th point ?
dvar int which[1..m] in points;

dexpr float maxDist=max(ordered i,j in 1..m) distance[which[i]][which[j]];

minimize maxDist;
subject to
{
  allDifferent(which);
}

{int} chosenPoints={which[k] | k in 1..m};
```

[image: Display through a python call from OPL]